# Can I add to the dbcontext in EF Core and also add that object to a list that is being returned and have it tracked?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to do three things but I'm not clear on what's happening behind the scenes here. What I'm trying to do is be given a list of keys that may or not already exist on the database. I want to 1) get what exists from the database, 2) add what doesn't exist to the database and the list to be returned, and 3) make sure that the list that is being returned with the newly added items is in the current context.

To sketch it out:

```
public async Task<List<DbModel>> GetDbModels(string userId, HashSet<int> keys)
{
    List<DbModel> dbModelList = await _context.DbModels.Where(f => f.UserId == userId && keys.Contains(f.SomeKey)).ToListAsync();

    List<int>keysNotOnDatabase = dbModelList.Where(f => !keys.Contains(f.SomeKey)).Select(f => f.SomeKey).ToList();

    foreach (var key in keysNotOnDatabase)
    {
        DbModel temp = new() { UserId = userId, SomeKey = key };
        _context.Add(temp);
        dbModelList.Add(temp);
    }

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    
    return dbModelList;
}
```

I feel like this is not going to work but that there must be some way that I am missing where I can do this without adding each item to the database, saving the database, and then re-selecting everything I've just added to the database? The reason I think this might work is because it is added to the _context so it should(?) be being tracked? Anyone have any insight here?

The purpose of all of this is so that there really should be no dedicated Add method because anything that should be added to these tables should only be created on a Get. The idea here is then that to save everything after manipulation, I should be able to just do:

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateDbModels(List<DbModel> list)
{
    try
    {
        _context.UpdateRange(list);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync()
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Further, is it possible that in the Get method I don't even need to save changes, just add to the context? I feel like no because it would likely need to be added before it could be updated? As in, if I add a new DbModel in the Get and later change its content, is it already being tracked, or would it need to be saved first to start being tracked?

Thank you very much for any and all insight!

Edit: fixed typo.

Comment: Based on my experience, what you're describing should work just fine, including adding the model to the context and deferring SaveChanges until after you've made additional changes. Try it!

Comment: Will do, thank you!